# My ~/.zprofile (paths, configuration and env variables)

Tags: zsh

This is my `.zprofile`, it recently got [nuked](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/758160/i-accidentally-moved-a-temp-zprofile-to-my-actual-zprofiles-file) so I remade it. I made it clearer and better then my previous `.zprofile` and then I heard about this site so I want to know how can I improve this code.

```
# Setting PATH for Python 3.11
export PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin:$PATH"
alias python=python3

export PYTHONPATH="/Users/jfami/Desktop:/Users/jfami/Desktop.noml:$PYTHONPATH"

# Setting PATH for Demonal
export PATH="/Users/jfami/Library/Demonal/bin:$PATH"

# Setting PATH for Sublime Text
export PATH="/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin:$PATH"

# Moving to a better directory
cd Desktop

# Aliases!
alias noml="python ~/Desktop/noml/app.py"
alias deppy="python ~/Desktop/deppy.py"
alias pylect="python ~/pylect/pylect-env/.pylect.py"

# ENV variables
export MYSQL_PASSWORD=$(cat MYSQL_PASSWORD)

# Configuration

termdx tebwhite > /dev/null 2>&1
termdx tefblack > /dev/null 2>&1
deppy cache-clear
demonal project select playground

# Print the art
echo -e "\e[0;35m<------------------------------------> \e[0m"
echo -e "\e[0;35mThe Terminal \e[0m"
echo -e "\e[0;35m<------------------------------------> \e[0m"
echo -e "\e[0;33mOS: $(uname)\e[0m"
echo -e "\e[0;36mUsername: $(whoami)\e[0m"
echo -e "\e[0;32mBrowser: $('/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome' --version)\e[0m"
```

Comment: Putting your dotfiles on GitHub helps against nuking them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do you really want *all* Python programs to look first in these directories?

> ```
> export PYTHONPATH="/Users/jfami/Desktop:/Users/jfami/Desktop.noml:$PYTHONPATH"
> ```

It might be appropriate to create very small shell scripts (which set the environment and `exec` the Python interpreter) for the few Python programs that actually use that path, and put them in `$HOME/bin` (or some other suitable place on your `$PATH`).

---

Don't do this:

> ```
> export MYSQL_PASSWORD=$(cat MYSQL_PASSWORD)
> ```

That's exposing your password in the environment variables of every process you run from this shell.  It's all too easy to leak that information to untrusted programs or other users.

---

You might *think* you only ever log in from one kind of terminal, but one day you'll find these hard-coded escape sequences a nuisance:

> ```
> echo -e "\e[0;35m<------------------------------------> \e[0m"
> ```

Instead, use `tput` to generate the correct codes for your actual `$TERM` if they exist.

Comment: 1. It won't be that much of a performance hog and a lot of scripts could use them which I don't always want in $HOME/bin.
2. So I shouldn't export it but should still assign it?
3. Thanks.

Comment: I'm with Toby on all counts. `Desktop` is not designed for keeping programs and libraries. It's a security risk to have passwords in variables in interactive shells. A better alternative is to store in `.my.cnf` with restricted permissions.

Comment: @The_AH, I was thinking first of correctness, rather than performance.  Since you put those `/Users/…` directories ahead of others, they may be picked up in preference to newer versions of the same modules later in the path.  It's not _wrong_ to do what you're doing, as long as you're fully aware of the implications.

Comment: @TobySpeight Interesting, I never do that but thanks anyways.

Answer (score 5):

Looks pretty good.

- If `/Users/jfami` becomes `$HOME`, you can use it on other boxes and other users can use it too.
- You probably also want to set your `MANPATH`, and possibly `INFOPATH`.  On the other hand, maybe you always look up the documentation online, and that’s just old-fashioned of me.
- If your system doesn’t by default, you might want to enable colors in `ls`, which on many distributions is the command given by `dircolors --sh`.
- Some of these commands [might be better for `.zshenv` or `.zshrc`,](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71253/what-should-shouldnt-go-in-zshenv-zshrc-zlogin-zprofile-zlogout) particularly the aliases, which I don’t believe would get inherited otherwise.
- If you often log in remotely, you might want to override your `LANG`, `LC_ALL` or `TZ`, although your terminal program likely has an option to set these.

Your profile is also very close to Bourne Shell syntax, which would work under any shell if you renamed `.zprofile` to `.profile`.  The only significant change you would need is to break up your `EXPORT` commands into two parts:

```sh
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin:$PATH"; export PATH
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I don't really use any shells except ZSH but I might consider the .zprofile to .profile change.

Comment: Why set `MANPATH`, and to what? I definitely consume docs primarily through `man`, and never had to tune this.

Comment: As far as I know `export foo=bar` is totally legit in Bash, is it not?

Comment: @janos `bash` is the Bourne Again Shell, which extends the syntax of `sh`. Other shells extend it in incompatible ways. For instance, `csh` and `tcsh` both use `setenv` rather than `export`.

Comment: @janos So, yes, `export FOO=/bar/baz` is also legal in a `.bash_profile`, but would not work on all shells.

Comment: @janos Many packages that you install will have a directory with their own `man` pages (typically with names like `pydoc3.11.1.gz` or `pydoc3.11.1` for `man -s 1 pydoc3.11`). It’s often named `man`, under the same directory as `bin`. You would add this to the beginning of `MANPATH` the same way that you add the `bin` directory to `PATH`.

Comment: @Davislor `export FOO=/bar/baz` should work on all shells that support POSIX syntax though. Antiquated Bourne shell variants might not support it, but is there any reasonable reason to stick with Bourne shell syntax instead of POSIX?

Comment: @muru Probably not. Most modern systems make `sh` a link to `bash`, which supports `export FOO=bar`.

Comment: @Davislor my question wasn't about bash, but about sticking to Bourne Shell instead of POSIX.

Comment: @muru To answer, I don’t think there’s any shell on a modern Linux, UNIX or BSD  where `export FOO=bar` does not work, but `FOO=bar; export FOO` does. There are some where neither works.